# Add multiple markers to rails map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have implemented google maps on my ruby on rails web application. I am displaying the map just fine and I am also able to place markers just fine. My issue is that I have 2 JavaScript functions that refresh the map and drop a marker on the map. I want to be able to keep the current map and just add another marker to the map with my functions. How can stop my map from refreshing to show more than 1 marker?

```
// application.js

var map;

function initMap() {
  var lat=29.732585;
  var lng=-95.462830;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 29.7604, lng: -95.3698},
      zoom: 10.25,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:29.732585,lng:-95.462830},
      map: map
  });
}

function getEmployee() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 29.7604, lng: -95.3698},
      zoom: 10.25,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:29.7154,lng:-95.3893},
      map: map
  });
}

function getLocation() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 29.7604, lng: -95.3698},
      zoom: 10.25,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:29.7560,lng:-95.3573},
      map: map
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `getEmployee()` or `getLocation()` you recreate the map, by calling `new google.maps.Map`. That's why your map is refreshing on each call.

Just remove this map recreating from these 2 functions. You create a map on `initMap()` call and store it in a global variable `map`, so it can be used in `getEmployee()` and `getLocation()` where you create a marker.

Comment: How do I create the map in my initMap() and save it as a global variable and in my getEmployee() and getLocation() how would I refer to the global map?

Comment: You already have global variable `map` by declaring it out of any function. When creating a map in `initMap()` you save it to that global variable. So just remove map reinitialization (`map = new google.maps.Map(...)`) from other 2 functions, and you're good.

Comment: Alright. I just want to make sure. So the other two functions would only consist of the marker info? as such.                                                                                  
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:29.7560,lng:-95.3573},
      map: map
  });

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did as you suggested.